# Significance of Enchantress' entry in the metahuman file

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad

In the [*Suicide Squad*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1386697/) (2016) mid-credits scene, Amanda Waller hands over a Metahuman file to Bruce Wayne. That file starts with Enchantress's entry followed by future Justice League members.

What is the significance of showing Enchantress in the file? They didn't show any other non Justice League Metahuman, then why did they show Enchantress?

Comment: I would consider the current title a spoiler, since you are giving away what the end credit scene is... but then again, I have seen question titles that reveal the death of characters and no one seems to care ...

Comment: @Oliver_C open for suggestions

Comment: @Oliver_C You seem to care and we're waiting for your improving edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is explicitly summed up in [Looper](http://www.looper.com/21149/explaining-mid-credits-scene-suicide-squad/):

> It's interesting to see that a file on Enchantress was included in Waller's metahuman dossiers, since the Squad defeated her. Enchantress' file was likely included for two reasons. First, **the dossiers were on metahumans in general, so Waller's judgements on character weren't really a factor in assembling this information. Enchantress was featured so Batman could develop *countermeasures* in case the witch's spirit, or someone with powers similar to hers, were to ever go bad.**

And also, it is noteworthy to quote the following excerpt from [ComicBook.com](http://comicbook.com/dc/2016/08/03/suicide-squad-ending-credits-scene-explained/):

> [...] After his meeting with Waller we now know how Bruce got his leads on the various League members whereabouts, and that he knows information well beyond the existence of metahumans. With the intel about The Enchantress clearly visible in the file, **Bruce now knows that the supernatural and mystical are also realities in this brave new metahuman world.**

So, in a nutshell the reason was that Waller wanted to make Bruce aware of the threat of Enchantress in case she or sort of equivalent rises again.